# How to show $I_k(t)=\int_\Omega (u(x,t)-k)_+^2 dx$ is absolutely continuous for any $u\in \mathring W^{1,1}_2(Q_T)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

$\Omega$ is bounded smooth domain of $\mathbb R^n$.

$Q_T=\Omega\times [0,T]$.

$\overset{\circ}{W}^{1,1}_2(Q_T)$ is the parabolic Sobolve space and is zero at $\partial \Omega \times[0,T]$.

$u_+=\max\{u,0\}$.

How to show for any $k>\sup_\limits{\partial_pQ_T} u$,   (where $\partial_pQ_T=\partial \Omega \times[0,T] \cup\Omega\times \{t=0\}$)
$$
I_k(t)=\int_\Omega (u(x,t)-k)^2_+dx
$$
is  [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Definition) on $[0,T]$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to show that $I_k$ is in $W^{1,1}(0,T)$. So multiply by $f’(t)$, where $f\in C^1_c(0,T)$, integrate in $t$ in $(0,T)$ and then use the definition of weak derivative to integrate by parts.Since the function $g(z)=(z-k)_+$ is Lipschitz continuous, you can apply the chain rule, which tells you that $v(x,t)=(u(x,t)-k)_+$ is in $W^{1,2}$ with
$$
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}(x,t)=\left\{
\begin{array}
[c]{ll}%
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t) & \text{if }u(x,t)>k,\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}%
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Hence,
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{T}f^{\prime}(t)I_{k}(t)\,dt  & =\int_{0}^{T}\int_{\Omega}f^{\prime
}(t)v^{2}(x,t)\,dxdt\\&=-\int_{0}^{T}\int_{\Omega}f(t)2v(x,t)\frac{\partial
v}{\partial t}(x,t)\,dxdt\\
& =-\int_{0}^{T}\int_{\Omega}f(t)2(u(x,t)-k)_{+}\frac{\partial u}{\partial
t}(x,t)\,dxdt\\
& =-\int_{0}^{T}f(t)\int_{\Omega}2(u(x,t)-k)_{+}\frac{\partial u}{\partial
t}(x,t)\,dxdt.
\end{align*}
This shows that the weak derivative of $I_{k}(t)$ is the function
$$
\omega(t)=\int_{\Omega}2(u(x,t)-k)_{+}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t)\,dx,
$$
which is integrable since by Holder's inequality
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{T}|\omega(t)|\,dt  & \leq2\int_{0}^{T}\int_{\Omega}(u(x,t)-k)_{+}%
\left\vert \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t)\right\vert \,dxdt\\
& \leq2\left(  \int_{0}^{T}\int_{\Omega}(u(x,t)-k)_{+}^{2}\,dxdt\right)
^{1/2}\left(  \int_{0}^{T}\int_{\Omega}\left\vert \frac{\partial u}{\partial
t}(x,t)\right\vert ^{2}dxdt\right)  ^{1/2}<\infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: I am sorry, the $u\in \overset{\circ}{W}^{1,1}_2(Q_T)$.  therefore, I can get the $I_k\in W^{1,1}$ by your way.  But I don't know why $I_k\in W^{1,1}$ means $I_k$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: Seemly, it is related to the Equivalent definitions of absolutely continuous in Wiki. But there is a little difference.

Comment: In one variable any Sobolev function admits a representation which is absolutely continuous